# Rigify glitch hands move on its own, root rotation

Tags: rigging, rigify, inverse-kinematics

[image: normal pose]

I've done rig the character, but when i move the root on the z axis the hand moves on its own like on the next picture.

[image: after rotating on the z axis]

The hand move up and down just because i rotate the root

I use these constraint
[image: the constraint that i use]
[image: hand rig]

Hand IK.

[image: the IK]